# Azure AD login failing when deployed on IIS

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, iis

Azure ad authentication working fine with Visual studio IIS Express. But when publish and deploy in IIS server throwing error.

The application built on .NET core 3.1

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/instance?authorization_endpoint=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize&api-version=1.1'.

 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/instance?authorization_endpoint=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize&api-version=1.1'.

 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..

 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

Comment: Seems like a connection issue.  Do you have access from the machine that runs IIS to Azure?

Comment: SSL is really TLS.  So you are failing the TLS authentication.  The error could be caused by a few issues.  Are you using a certificate?  The certificate may be missing on the server.  A IIS is a window 2012 machine which is defaulting to TLS 1.0/1.1.  You probably need to specify TLS 1.2/1.3 to work.  You can check with a sniffer and compare TLS version on working system with non working system.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure your IIS server has TLS 1.2 support enabled.

Also, enable **TLS 1.2** support in your .net core application by adding below in startup, in the beginning of Main method of Program.cs.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol;
```

Read more about TLS update in Azure [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/updates/azuretls12/)